# Better way to pick random point on earth

Tags: php, math, geolocation

I am using

```
$lat=rand(0-pi()*1000000,pi()*1000000)/1000000;
$lon=rand(0-pi()*1000000,pi()*1000000)/1000000;
```

to pick a random point on earth(in radians)  however this method results in points being closer together near polls then near equator since 1 deg of $lon is a smaller distance near the polls then at the equator.

Any ideas on how to get a better distribution?

Comment: My initial thought was that a different coordinate system, such as polar coordinates which use rho and theta angles, would work. But upon reflection I realized that wouldn't help. You've essentially got a spherical tiling problem: you want a system of tiles of approximate area _X_ covering a sphere. Once you have that you can number them and use normal random number mechanisms to choose one. So perhaps you should be Googling "tiling a sphere".

Comment: What is the range of values that you want ?

Comment: Consider re-writing this as a math problem and posting it to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is an excellent article that describes exactly your problem and offers some solutions to it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article on Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) you need something like this:

```
$long = pi() - 2 * pi() * rand(0, 1000000) / 1000000;
$lat = pi() / 2 - acos(2 * rand(0, 1000000) / 1000000 - 1);
```

Comment: by my understanding of the article `$lat=acos(rand(0,1000000)/500000-1);`  please note I simplified the `2/1000000`

Comment: In this case, it will be between 0 and pi(). I thought you need it between -pi() / 2 and pi() / 2.